# How to connect some Django template to html hyperlink?

Tags: python, django, templates

[1]For example i have such html page(main page)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJlbd.png

Also there are three hyperlink tags, and i want to generate some template for each tag when it's clicked.
For example, if "home" is clicked, i will generate the same page with template of all posts of my blog.
If 'create' is clicked, i'll generate the same page with another template that contains a form for creating of a post.
It's a code of my **main page**

```html
<body>
   <div class="left-menu">
      <img src="/static/POST PROJECT.png" class="logo" alt="">
      <ul class="left-ul">
         <li class="left-li">
            <a href="{% url 'main'%}">Home</a>
         </li>
         <li class="left-li">
            <a href="{% url 'main'%}">Create</a>
         </li>
         <li class="left-li">
            <a href="{% url 'main'%}">Find</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="main">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
   </div>
</body>
```

My **urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name='main')
]
```

It's my **views.py**

```py
def main(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `context` for that. You are already passing it, but it's only an empty dict. One way to do it is by modifying your `main` view to accept a slug, and do something according to that slug's value.

---

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('/<str:slug>', views.main, name='main')
]
```

---

**views.py**

```py
def main(request, slug):
    context = {}

    if slug == "home":
        posts = # query all your posts here
        context["posts"] = posts
    elif slug == "create":
        form # create the form instance here
        context["create_form"] = form
    elif slug == "somethingelse":
        somethingelse = # do something else
        context["somethingelse"] = somethingelse

    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

---

**index.html**

```html
<div class="left-menu">
    <img src="/static/POST PROJECT.png" class="logo" alt="">
    <ul class="left-ul">
        <li class="left-li">
            <a href="{% url 'main' slug='home' %}">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="left-li">
            <a href="{% url 'main' slug='create' %}">Create</a>
        </li>
        <li class="left-li">
            <a href="{% url 'main' slug='find' %}">Find</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```